# How to remove an agent from a mesos cluster?

Tags: azure, mesos

In a IaaS context (Azure, actually), I removed a machine from our mesos cluster without scheduling the maintenance window to tear it down before.

This agent and the tasks belonging to it now appears as "unreachable" on the UI, I tried to use `/maintenance/schedule` and `/machine/down`, which worked, but the agent and tasks are still appearing as "unreachable" on the UI, any way to get rid of it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's up to your framework what to do with this task. Mesos itself lost connection with an agent which does not respond to healthcheck. This caused marking agent and all its tasks as [unreachable](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/task-state-reasons/#for-state-task_unreachable). If a framework is partition-aware it should handle this situation. If not you may need to wait until the task is marked as [failed](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/task-state-reasons/#for-state-task_lost).

> [`--agent_reregister_timeout=VALUE`](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/configuration/master/)
>   The timeout within which an agent is expected to re-register. Agents re-register when they become disconnected from the master or when a new master is elected as the leader. Agents that do not re-register within the timeout will be marked unreachable in the registry; if/when the agent re-registers with the master, any non-partition-aware tasks running on the agent will be terminated. NOTE: This value has to be at least 10mins. (default: 10mins)

Comment: Thanks, do you know if a way to reset the "unreachable" agents counter exists ? Ie. after a scale down of the whole cluster, for agents that will never be available again. It's not a big deal, but we'd like to keep this counter "clean" to be able to monitor it to troubleshoot network partitioning issue.

Comment: Restarting masters could clean up this.

Comment: restart master could clean up unreachable tasks, and I can reuse the old task_id, but it seems if I don't clean up the old tasks in old machine,  it will make master crash. There is another way to clean up unreachable tasks without restarting master.